# Are there published encounters that send you into an illusion or dream state?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, illusion, portals

Our DM in a recent adventure had us transported into a matrix like illusion when we used a portal. We thought we were traveling back to Undermountain from an orbiting satellite that was occupied by Githyanki, but instead we ended up in Waterdeep. Only, to find out after some time, that something was *not right* about Waterdeep, and in the end we found out that our bodies were actually held in some Matrix-like (as in the movie) pods operated by Mind Flayers, and what we experienced was just a very detailed illusion or hallucination. (And of course, the question then became how to escape).

I found this was a cool twist, but I also suspect that this effect is not part of the normal adventure, because for one, the DM has heavily modded the published adventure to make it more exciting, and secondly, in all my years of DMing, I have never run into a portal that did not just transport the body but also sent you to an illusion or dream state. But who knows -- I certainly have not read all the official modules that have been published over the years. This made me wonder - was anything like that published? I'm mostly interested in unusual portals, but other trigger effects that let you end up in a transition to another environment that is an illusion without you realizing it are good too.

Anything from TSR, WotC, including magazines like Dungeon or White Dwarf or novels from authors like Greenwood, Gygax or Salvatore would be a viable source.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I of course cannot know for sure as I am not the DM but I'm pretty confident it was a portal not a 3.5 psion power. The adventure was 5e, and we used the portal on the way up there already. I think a lich with connections to Halaster asked him to rig it, because we stole her spellbooks.

Comment: What makes you think the portal didn't just lead directly to the physical pod(s)? The portal isn't sending you into a dream or illusion, it just sends you somewhere where you're immediately trapped in said illusion. Could the Mind Flayers have just identified a particular portal end point and set up the pod there?

Comment: Like @HeyICanChan, I can think of some examples that don't involve physical portals _per se_ - one in an old BECMI module (magic dust trap) and one in a web comic (epic illusion spell trap).  The "[Lotus Eater Machine](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine)" entry on TV Tropes has a 2nd edition psionic power and a 5th edition magic item.  If these are within your scope I can post as an answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, I did not think of that. Yes, it is possible, I guess — if you immediately get send of into the matrix from there so there is no brief flash of awareness you are in a pod. We did not have any kind of save/check, it was automatic, but I can see why, asking for them kind of gives it away. A brief „vision“ of a pod might too of course.

Comment: @Kirt, I‘ll amend the question. These kinds of effects where you do not know what is real and what not are a common trope in literature, and would be interesting to see how they are handled in adventures

Comment: This is hard because your both trying to describe what happened to you to figure into it and asking a more general question about “similar” things. But how do we know if it’s similar if we don’t know what your DM did? When you say “you” do you mean physically transport your body into a dream?

Comment: @NotArch No, your body could be sent or stay anywhere. Impirtant is tgat your mind and adventure experiencexends up in s dream or illusion without the player knowing it.

Comment: Doesn’t a portal usually transport you physically? Is it still a portal if it isn’t something you pass through? Maybe I don’t fully understand what a portal is, but based on your other questions, it sure seems physical.

Comment: If you aren’t actually asking about portals, can you clarify your question to the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149402/discussion-between-nobody-the-hobgoblin-and-notarch).

Comment: I have just begun running Dungeon of the Mad Mage.  As part of this dungeon, there is indeed something very similar to what you describe, with illithids, pods, and an alternate version of Waterdeep.  While your DM may have modded what you experienced, I can put the official version in my answer if you would like.

Comment: @Kirt, Yes - we are still playing the module, so I don't want to read those levels myself.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Got it, feel free to lmk when you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SPOILERS AHEAD

**X2 Castle Amber (BECMI, Expert Level Adventure - 1981)**

In room 50, the alchemical laboratory,

> ...concealed vents will open and begin to fill the room with a black powdery cloud which moves as though it is alive...Every round a character breathes in the fumes or comes into direct contact with the powdery cloud, the character must save vs. Spells or fall asleep...This particular alchemical preparation can cause exceptionally vivid dreams (or nightmares) and has the magical property of possibly making those dreams (or nightmares) come true.

The module asks the DM to make up the dreams caused by the trap, but gives a number of suggestions, many of which involve the players believing that their PC has been transported somewhere else and that what is happening to them is real.

As an example:

> A dream that all the plant life in the world suddenly gains demonic intelligence and plans to take over the world. The character is the only person who knows the truth. Fortunately he or she discovers an ancient artifact which, when destroyed, returns the plants to normal. Unfortunately no one will believe the PC’s story.

One of my players' PC's in the 80's had this dream, and to this day he is still bitter that no one believed her.

One of the dreams actually physically transports the PC to another location, where they remain out of play and dreaming unless and until the rest of the party can find them.  **This most closely matches the original request for a portal trap that simultaneously affects PC's bodies and minds.**

> A dream of a strange land called Averoigne...The character will disappear from the room and will be out of play, but will awake in the clearing on the far side of the Gate of the Silver Keys at just about the same time that the party actually arrives and opens the Gate.

The module does not say how long the characters sleep in the laboratory, only that regardless of the length or complexity of the dream, they all awake at the same time.  Presumably this would give the Amber family, were they still present, the chance to collect and imprison anyone who had intruded on their laboratory.

**The Illithiad (Second Edition, 1998)**

According to [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine),

> The Illithiad has the Microcosm psionic power, which allows an illithid to take over a victim's mind and make them think they have been transported to a paradise-like fantasy world. In fact, they're just standing around not doing anything. The power negates all normal sensory input and the victim can only be brought out of it if they can realize that what their senses are experiencing is false.

**Order of the Stick 885-891 (3.5e based, 2013)**

The Order triggers an epic-level illusion trap that allows them to each have a 'Happy Ending' to their quest.  Most of the party share a common illusion, but Belkar is in a separate illusion because his conception of a happy ending is not shared by the others.  It is unclear how long they are trapped, but for "at least a few hours" because it has been long enough for Roy to be really hungry but not so long that he needs to shave.  Elan manages to break them out of it when he realizes that while the other's happy endings are at least plausible, his is so stupid and childish that it should never happen, and yet it does.  Once they are free, Roy tells Elan that he did well, and Elan is so unused to the complement that he suspects they are *still* in some sort of illusory wish-fulfillment trap.

**Dragonlance: Shadow of the Dragon Queen (Fifth Edition, 2022)**

According to [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine),

> [T]he *mirror of reflected pasts* paralyzes anyone who looks into its depths by showing them an idealized version of their own past, unless they make their saving throw to resist the effect.

Comment: Those don’t sound like a portal into dreams, but I may not understand the question parameters.

Comment: @NotArch They are not - with the possible exception of the X2 dreams that can in some cases physically transport you places if they become real.  I asked whether OP wanted to restrict answers to portals only, and they modified the question to include "I'm mostly interested in unusual portals, but other trigger effects that let you end up in a transition to another environment that is an illusion without you realizing it are good too."  After receiving that confirmation I posted my answer.

Comment: Okay, I’m still confused as to what OP is looking for here, but seems like you do:)

Comment: @NotArch Updated with a reference to at least one dream-trap that also functions as a physical portal.

Comment: How does a 2013 webcomic arc fit the 'from TSR & WotC' criteria of the question?

Comment: @user10063 It doesn't.  IMO, it does fit the "novels from authors like Greenwood, Gygax or Salvatore would be a viable source" criteria though, particularly since most of the Gygax novels were explicitly _not_ TSR and were published under New Infinities.  But just to be sure, I proposed the webcomic to OP in a [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208805/are-there-published-encounters-that-send-you-into-an-illusion-or-dream-state/208807?noredirect=1#comment573561_208805) and he did not reject it.

Answer (score -2):

You suspect partially wrongly; you just got done with Stardock from level 16, and since you didn't have a TPK earlier in the dungeon, DM fiat swept you up into the most irresistible fun-for-the-DM plotline on level 17: the psi pods and Alterdeep.

> ###### A Visit to Alterdeep
>
> If your party of adventurers is incapacitated or killed in Undermountain, you have an unusual option for keeping both them and the campaign alive: the characters could awaken in an alternate version of the Yawning Portal that is part of a psionically generated simulation of Waterdeep called Alterdeep,

As for other adventures: the module *[Six Faces of Death](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/dragon/21/DRA21_sixfacesdeath.pdf)* contains a fake happy ending trap set by a villain.

> The
> characters are then told that a dimensional portal in
> the cube can take them home, whereupon they are led
> to area 6.25. As soon as they pass through the doorway
> into this area, that doorway disappears behind them.
>
> Everything in the new environment appears to be
> real. Moreover, the characters are also greeted by up to
> 1d4 + 1 people or creatures that seem to belong at the
> new location—all of them manifested by the oblex. If the
> area would normally have a larger group of people, they
> are unexpectedly absent or show up later, but no more
> than two to five other creatures are ever seen at the
> same time.
>
> In reality, the characters remain in the barracks as
> transformed by the balhannoth. The skull lord simply
> wants them to waste time figuring out how to get out
> of this false environment while the pixelating curse
> overcomes them.
>
> Among the many things likely to give away the false
> nature of this homecoming, any object created by
> the balhannoth is clearly a fake. Books turn out to be
> filled with blank paper, mechanical devices are crude,
> nonfunctioning duplicates, gold and jewels turn out to
> be made of paste or tin, and so forth.

Comment: Note that OP [specifically requested](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/208805/are-there-published-encounters-that-send-you-into-an-illusion-or-dream-state/210799#comment578235_208805) not answering with content from the adventure they are currently playing.  Also, your answer would be improved by citing the source of _Six Faces of Death_ (is it official WoTC content, D&D Beyond, etc.) as well as expanding a bit beyond the quote to explain why the happy ending is fake.

Comment: @Kirt A) This answer doesn't contain anything he hasn't already experienced, he only asks that 'those levels' not be described; B) Noted, but I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect answerers to, before answering, have pored through all the many, many hidden-by-default comments to find special requests from the asker that haven't been edited into the question itself.

Comment: No, I don't think it is reasonable either - which is why I alerted you myself.